# Once I cancel my apple Music subscription will it still make me pay a months worth or does it end straight away?

Tags: music, user-account

I cancelled my Apple Music last month and deleted the account but Apple is still taking $12 out of my account for this month.  Is this normal or do I have to contact Apple Support again?

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel the subscription 24 hours or less before the renewal date you may still be charged.

> Your subscription might renew if you don’t cancel more than 24 hours before your renewal date.

- https://support.apple.com/HT204939

If you cancelled more than 24 hours contact [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com).